# After deploying a new version to the web app should detect that there was a new version deployed. How do I implent in my vue application

Tags: vue.js, deployment, service-worker

I need to implement "After deploying a new version to the web app should detect that there was a new version deployed". Is this possible using service worker? How I do it? If not what is the method I need to use?

Need a implementation for "After deploying a new version to the web app should detect that there was a new version deployed."

Comment: webpack or vite?

Comment: use a simple replace plugin to inject git last commit hash into the source code. compare to stored in the local storage

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev, it is webapp